# make diffrent template on last six post published

Tags: loop

I wanted to make last six posts different template from other posts but I can't get it work below are my loop code inserted on my index.php

```
$last_no_of_posts = 6;
$ctr = 0;

while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); 

   if ($ctr < $wp_query->found_posts - $last_no_of_posts) {
      // require special template
      get_template_part( 'loop', 'special' );
   } else {
      // regular template
      get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
   }
   $ctr++;

}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to insert this content? In the `index.php` file, `single.php`, ...?

Comment: I insert this loop on index.php

Comment: This seems like it should work. What exactly happens? Try echoing variables in the loop and see if they are what you expect from iteration to iteration.

Comment: Do you have files named `loop-special.php` and `loop-index.php` in your theme directory?

Comment: @Rarst it doesnt show anything even to post that should use `get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );`

Answer (score 1):

As written, you are checking the total post count against your counter. That is, `$wp_query` is the total post count for the query  not the per page count.

Now, assume 30 posts total in the query with 10 posts per page. Your counter starts and will get all the way to 10, but `$ctr < $wp_query->found_posts - $last_no_of_posts` is always true. `$ctr` will be 10 at the end of that loop but `$wp_query->found_posts - $last_no_of_posts` will be 30 - 10, or 20. The same with the second page of results, because your counter starts over. The same with the page after that. Under that circumstance, and many like it, `$ctr` is always less than `found_posts` minus your counter. The only way this identifies the last six is if all results are on one page-- no pagination. Perhaps that is what you are doing, and that is what you want.

However, if you need to identify the last six on each page of pagination you need to rewrite it to use `post_count` not `found_posts`:

```
while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); 

   if ($ctr < $wp_query->post_count - $last_no_of_posts) {
      // require special template
      get_template_part( 'loop', 'special' );
   } else {
      // regular template
      get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
   }
   $ctr++;

}
```

If you want the last six on the very last page of pagination you need (untested):

```
if ($wp_query->current_post >= $wp_query->found_posts - $last_no_of_posts) {
```

Comment: I need it to identify the last six post of total post not per page :)

Comment: As I explained, what you are doing is still not going to work except in some restricted circumstances because your counter won't continue incrementing over each page but will reset on each page. You need to be checking the `current_post` value as per the last sentence in the answer.